# Handle multiple input values with React Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, input, use-state, redux-toolkit, multiple-input

I'm trying to handle two form input values and save data to store with Redux Toolkit on submit. Seems simple but haven't really got the hang of it, yet.

My first thought was to keep the input values locally with useState and set data to store only when submitting the form. Just to prevent rendering on input change. But when submitting I'd like to save it to store.

```
export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    length: null,
    width: null
  });
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setUser({ ...user, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // set data to store on submit
    dispatch(setUser);
    console.log(setUser);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="length"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Add Length"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="width"
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Add Width"
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <User />
    </div>
```

And here's my slice function:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    length: null,
    width: null
  },
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user.length = action.payload;
      state.user.width = action.payload;
    }
  }
});

export const { user, setUser } = userSlice.actions;
export const selectUser = (state) => state.user;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

I've managed it to work with one input but not when there's multiple inputs. [See codesandbox for full example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-toolkit-multiple-inputs-khrbb)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it would be better if you added the most significant parts of the code in the question, just to prevent problems with the linked content

Comment: Oh, sorry! Didn't know that, thanks. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are dispatching the setUser action with an empty value

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // set data to store on submit
        dispatch(setUser);
        console.log(setUser);
      };
```

Change it to this.

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // set data to store on submit
        dispatch(setUser(user));
        console.log(setUser);
      };
```

And in ***userSlice.js*** change it to this.

```
 reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.length = action.payload?.length;
      state.width = action.payload?.width;
    }
  }
```

[here is the codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-toolkit-multiple-inputs-forked-lb4ff?file=/src/features/userSlice.js:162-343)

Comment: Wow, thanks! 
Would you recommend this approach if the purpose was to make this project easy to scale up or would you go for a different approach?

Comment: yeah, this is approach is fine.